# Longest Matching SubPath Between Two Paths

Tags: javascript, string

I need to compare two paths to get the index of the last char of the max subpath in common between them. For ex:

```
/folder1/folder2/folder3/ybjagh/
/folder1/folder2/folder3/yAAAAAA
```

In this case the max subpath would be /folder1/folder2/folder3/ because /folder1/folder2/folder3/y doesn't make it a complete path. The index returned would be 23 then and not 25.

I know how to do it but I think I might be overthinking this. Is there a simple javascript code that looks neat that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: Keep matching, only persisting the matched string when you see a `/`, then return the persisted string once something doesn't match?

Comment: yeah, I know a simple way, but it might not be as simple as yours, so, you show me yours, I'll show you mine ...

Comment: Just what Evan said above...

//pseudocode
while(iterator < path1.length && iterator< path2.length) {
   //if different char, break
   //if char is /, save in result;
   iterator++;
}
return result;

Comment: Dang it.. I'm new here.. can I format the comment it above? Four spaces didn't help...

Comment: @JohnSmith only inline formatting in comments - so surround with a backtick (`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one off the top of my head - there's probably a better way using array.reduce too - this way you don't need to persist a match or any such stuff, works on one "folder" of the path at a time

```
function longpath(a, b) {
    var cont = true;
    b = b.split('/');
    return a.split('/').filter(function(item, index) {
        return cont = cont && b[index] === item;
    }).join('/')+'/';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This is more like what I'm looking for... I know how to write it in an ugly way... although easier to understand way I guess...